# Completely remove office 2013 preview

Tags: microsoft-office, uninstall

I tried out office 2013 thinking it might be better than openoffice.org, but I was really dissapointed.

In my past experiences it is nearly impossible to completely remove office without screwing up windows - that's when I originally switched to openoffice.  How can I make sure that I remove every file and folder that was installed with office 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it will likely always leave some remnants of itself behind, but after uninstalling via Programs and Features, you can go into Program Files\Microsoft Office and delete everything under the Office15 folder, if the folder still exists.

Comment: (As an example) even if I were to do that and re install it it would you use same key that is currently installed which means there are still more files around. I have used ccleaner after the uninstall and even then I know that there are parts of it around my system

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy yes you could use ccleaner and get the reg keys, but short of using CMC's solution in the future, there's really no 100% way.

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy - If you install the Office 2013 RTM the install would NOT allow you to use the same keys.  I assume thats what your attempting to do.  Furthermore one can remove Office 2013 simply by using the uninstaller and your system will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more advanced tool for uninstalling than "uninstall programs" from the control panel.
Such tool is this one (free version available) > [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).
You have uninstall modes from basic to advanced where it will delete leftovers and registry entries for you. It's a pretty decent solution imo.

Comment: Wouldn't running ccleaner after the install have the same effect?  Or is revo-uninstaller better?

Comment: For future reference, the advanced mode allows you to capture what files the installer modifies or adds, meaning that you can easily undo the installation by deleting the relevant files.  Revo Uninstaller is better at analyzing installed programs than ccleaner in my experience.

Comment: I think Revo might have the edge since it scans for some dependencies and not only for useless registries as would CCleaner. That said i think CCleaner is a great program as well.

Comment: Programs like Revo are such a scam.  They do NOTHING other that `Add/Remove Programs` doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

on most new computers, Office now has this "Office 15 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component" that runs an office install on the first click.

Even if you delete the trial office before you do anything else, this click-to-run "feature" will much up any install of office.

This registry hack shows how to get rid of that feature.  Don't do it if you are not comfortable in the registry.

https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/office-2013/solved-how-to-uninstall-office-15-click-to-run-extensibility-component/

By the way, it took NINE installs / 8 deinstalls to clean out everything.  That is because I did not do the registry first.

Answer (score 0):

The only bullet-proof way to really uninstall the Office 2013 Preview after it expires is the Manual Method described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501

You can try to use the Microsoft Fixit solution given on the top of the page, but most probably, it would fail or only partially succeed.

Try the manual method. It did work perfectly. To summarize, you'll have to do these things:

1. Delete folders and files from Program Files
2. Mess around (a lot) in Registry settings --> A fairly redundant and drudge work, but it did the trick :)
3. Mess around with system services, etc.

If you don't have the stomach for it, still give it a try. Just follow the instructions, and everything will be alright!